# Printing Numbers in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Im trying to do the following in the list below: Let say list one consists of (1234) and list 2 is (5678) I am trying to print it in the following way (15263748) This is what I have for now but I am not sure where to go after this. Of course right now the code below prints it like 12 34 it should be 1 3 2 4

```
   (define (arrange-list lst1 lst2)
  (append lst1 lst2))
 (arrange-list '(12) '(34))
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the input lists look like `(1234)` or `(1 2 3 4)`? they're different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common procedure, usually known as `interleave`. Assuming that the input lists have the same length, we can write the following implementation from scratch, using explicit recursion:

```
(define (interleave lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      '()
      (cons (car lst1)
            (interleave lst2 (cdr lst1)))))
```

The trick is taking one element from one list, and then from the other until both lists are exhausted. A more idiomatic solution in Racket would be to use built-in procedures, like this:

```
(define (interleave lst1 lst2)
  (flatten (map cons lst1 lst2)))
```

Either way it works as expected:

```
(interleave '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6 7 8))
=> '(1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lists aren't of equal length, this is my solution which works albeit is not as elegant as the one mentioned in the other answer.

Basically, we maintain a variable `x` while recursively calling the procedure that indicates which list needs processing currently. The first list is indicated by `1` and the second, `2`.

```
(define (print-alt A B x)(cond
                ((and (null? A) (null? B)) '())                                                                                       
                 ((= 1 x) (cond
                           ((null? A) (print-alt A B 2))
                           (else (append (list (car A)) (print-alt (cdr A) B 2)))))
                (else (cond
                      ((null? B) (print-alt A B 1))
                      (else (append (list (car B)) (print-alt A (cdr B) 1)))))))
```

Here is the output:

```
(print-alt (list 1 2 3 4 5 6) (list 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 123) 1)
(1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8 5 9 6 10 11 12 123)
```